# Derive a formula for the least squares solution with two column vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus, least-squares, applications

I am new to this least square solution. If **a** and **b** are column vectors in $\Bbb R^N$, then wouldn't the least square solution of **a**$x$=**b** be $A^TAx = A^Tb$?

I am really having a hard to visualizing this.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Mathstudent It would be $\mathbf a^T \mathbf a\,x = \mathbf a^T \mathbf b$.  Note that this is ultimately just an equation of the form $px = q$ for numbers $p,q$.

Comment: *I am really having a hard to visualizing this.* What is the purpose of visualizing it? Also, what are $x$ and $A$ exactly?